# Resize image depending on window height

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per the title, I want to be able to reduce image size when window height becomes smaller.
It's working for reducing part but I want it to get the original height back when window height is greater than specified.

I know this part `$('.model').height();` is wrong.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() { 
  var h = $(window).height(); 

  if (h < 850) {
     $('.model').height(600); 
  } else { 
     $('.model').height(); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: try `$('.model').css("height","")`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to store the height of `.model` in a variable and restore it like this:

```
var originalHeight = $('.model').height();  

$(window).on('load resize', function() { 
   var h = $(window).height();

  if (h < 850) {
     $('.model').height(600); 
  } else { 
     $('.model').height(originalHeight); 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting height back into (the default) "auto" when you want the original size back?
     $(window).on('load resize', function() { 
     var h = $(window).height();

```
if (h < 850) {
   $('.model').height(600); 
} else { 
   $('.model').css("height","auto"); 
} 
});
```